# Get result of rest request instead of response?

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

I have the following function in my controller.

```
RestRequestsSrvc.getUserDetail()
  .then(
    function (response) {
      $scope.user.userDetail = response;
    },
    function (error) {
      // TODO
    });
```

If I type

`console.log(RestRequestsSrvc.getUserDetail());`

the console logs a promise. I want to set a variable the the response. How can I modify my code so that I get the response instead of a promise?

Comment: Ehm. You can't do this. Request – some async thing. To deal with async things you need promises. Anyway, even if async request will be resolved in 0 ms - it is async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a promise because your request is async.

You should wait the response,

Putting the console.log inside the callback function should print your info.

```
RestRequestsSrvc.getUserDetail()
  .then(
    function (response) {
      $scope.user.userDetail = response;
      console.log(response);
    },
    function (error) {
      // TODO
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the console.log into the promise .then

```
RestRequestsSrvc.getUserDetail()
  .then(
    function (response) {
      $scope.user.userDetail = response;
      console.log(response);
    },
    function (error) {
      // TODO
    });
```

The thing is that when you call the function it will be executed but will not wait for the result, that's why you get a promise. The .then stuff is called once the request is done executing. That's where you handle your success or error callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Requests to the server are asynchronous, meaning that you must handle the response inside the callback.

You could use async false flag but this is not recommended if you have independent modules that executed later in the code.